# plotting regression line for each record in a nested list

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested, tidyverse, purrr

I have an example that nests data into a list, adds a linear model to each tibble in the list, adds the regression coefficients to each record in the list, and adds 2 different ggplot objects to each record in the list. I want to plot the regression line on a separate figure for each record. I can get geom_smooth to do exactly what I'm after, but geom_abline appears to add a regression for each record in the list one every figure (my example has three records, hence three lines on each figure instead of the desired single line for each record.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

iris_species <- iris %>%  
  group_by(Species) %>%  
  nest()

# build model functions
model <- function(iris) {
  lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
}

# map models to the tibble
iris_species <- iris_species %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, model))

iris_species # look at the structure

# add glance and tidy results to list
iris_species <- iris_species %>% 
  mutate(t = map(model, tidy)
         )

# unnest tidy list
iris_species_g <- iris_species %>% 
  unnest(t) %>% 
  select(Species, term, estimate) %>% 
  spread(key = term, value = estimate) %>%
  select(Species, `(Intercept)`, Sepal.Width) 

# pain down a list for species and data
iris_species_list <- iris_species %>% 
  select(Species, data, model)

# join  
iris_species_coeffs <- left_join(iris_species_list, iris_species_g, by = 'Species')

# add figures to list
iris_species_figs <- iris_species_coeffs %>% 
  mutate(plot1 = map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
                       geom_point() + 
                       geom_smooth(se = TRUE, size = 1, color = 'grey')
                     ) 
         ) 

iris_species_figs <- iris_species_figs %>% 
  mutate(plot2 = map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
                      geom_point() +
                      geom_abline(intercept = `(Intercept)`, slope = Sepal.Width, color = 'blue')
                    )
         ) 

iris_species_figs

# make figures
iris_species_figs$plot1 # works as expected

iris_species_figs$plot2 # does not
```

Here is the final product from the above code:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  Species    data              model    `(Intercept)` Sepal.Width plot1    plot2   
  <fct>      <list>            <list>           <dbl>       <dbl> <list>   <list>  
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>          2.64       0.690 <S3: gg> <S3: gg>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>          3.54       0.865 <S3: gg> <S3: gg>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>          3.91       0.902 <S3: gg> <S3: gg>
```

running the last two lines shows the issue. The geom_smooth code in plot1 creates 1 figure for each record with the data from each record and applies the smoothing line to each figures. However, goem_abline in plot2, does not. It appears to plot all 3 lines (one from each record) on each of the three figures. Any suggestions as to how to get goem_abline to behave like geom_smooth would be much apprecaited.

Comment: `purrr` and `ggplot2` are part of `tidyverse`, so you don't need to load them, again, separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function you're using for `plot 2` is mapping ONLY the `data` and for intercept and slope it sees a vector of 3 elements. That's why you see 3 lines in each plot.

You have to use `pmap` in order to `map` all the info / columns you need to use for each plot.

Try this:

```
iris_species_figs <- iris_species_figs %>% 
  mutate(plot2 = pmap(list(data,`(Intercept)`,Sepal.Width), 
                      function(a,b,c) ggplot(a, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
                       geom_point() +
                       geom_abline(intercept = b, slope = c, color = 'blue')
  )
  )
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I am curious however to better understand your use of pmap and the function (a,b,c). I can see that feed pmap a list (each record of data, intercept and slope), then use those terms as the arguments for geom_abline. Is this necessary or for clarity? One the surface it looks like a technique to rename awkward argument name, `(Intercept)` for example. Regardless I appreciate the answer. I have always found the documentation for the map family a bit obtuse.

Comment: `map2` accepts 2 inputs and you can use either something like `~ .x +.y` or something like `function(a,b) a+b`. However, `pmap` accepts 3+ inputs so you have to use something like `function(a,b,c) a+b+c`, because there's nothing after `.x` and `.y` to use. And as you said, you need to create a list of inputs to pass to `pmap` as inputs.